# MSAL SSO and Authentication Brokers

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I've been working on getting SSO working with Intune as the auth broker using the Native ADAL plugins.  Getting that setup seems to be fairly straight forward for Android and iOS (although it requires Microsoft Authenticator) once you have the redirect uris setup correctly.

I'd like more details on how to enable the same sort of SSO experience using MSAL (particularly for iOS).  I've been unable to find documentation on how to expect the SSO flow to work in MSAL and how it integrates with various brokers (like Intune and Authenticator).  Is there any documentation around this? Does it call out the brokers like ADAL does or does it use a different mechanism?  What's microsoft's recommendation for this sort of behavior once we move to MSAL?

Answer (score 0):

So right now, authentication brokers are not supported by MSAL. The product group is working on it though, but that functionality is not there today. Expect it should be there by end of year.

Answer (score 0):

MSAL support with broker on iOS is available starting with [0.3.0](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/releases/tag/0.3.0) and is currently in preview. Integration instructions can be found in the Wiki [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/wiki/Migrating-from-ADAL-Objective-C-to-MSAL-Objective-C#brokermicrosoft-authenticator-support).

Android support for broker with MSAL is currently in development.

Comment: Hi Brian.  Do you know if MSAL.js (microsoft-authentication-library-for-js ) works with Microsoft Intune?

Comment: @DeanB_Develop Depends on what scenarios you're trying to support. Multifactor and incremental scopes are supported today. MSAL.js publishes a [roadmap on their wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki) - new scenarios may be supported in an upcoming release.